# xfa worker is throwing Java Script event evaluation failed

Tags: java, itext, xfa

I am using `iText` to flatten PDF and till now it's working fine.
For production purpose I have used `log4j` to log my application's error and info.

While going down the log file I am seeing an error coming from `iText XFAWorker` (although my flattening procedure is working fine).

I also noticed that `XFAWorker` is using `slf4j` for internal logging.

Can anybody help me to solve this error, here I am attaching the whole log.

```
XFA form element: xfa[0].form[0].Form2_Dtls[0]
Event 'initialize'
org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot call method "indexOf" of undefined (js#612)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3687)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3665)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError(ScriptRuntime.java:3693)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError2(ScriptRuntime.java:3712)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.undefCallError(ScriptRuntime.java:3731)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.getPropFunctionAndThisHelper(ScriptRuntime.java:2258)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.getPropFunctionAndThis(ScriptRuntime.java:2251)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Interpreter.interpretLoop(Interpreter.java:1317)
    at script.initializeWithoutCheckForm(js:612)
    at script.formInintialize(js:8)
    at script(js:4)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Interpreter.interpret(Interpreter.java:815)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.InterpretedFunction.call(InterpretedFunction.java:109)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:394)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3091)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.InterpretedFunction.exec(InterpretedFunction.java:120)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Context.evaluateString(Context.java:1079)
    at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.xtra.xfa.js.RhinoJsObject.evaluateScript(RhinoJsObject.java:98)
    at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.xtra.xfa.js.RhinoJsObject.evaluateScript(RhinoJsObject.java:73)
    at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.xtra.xfa.js.JsContainer.execOwnEvent(JsContainer.java:50)
    at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.xtra.xfa.js.JsContainer.execEvent(JsContainer.java:42)
    at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.xtra.xfa.positioner.Positioner.execEvent(Positioner.java:412)
    at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.xtra.xfa.XFAFlattener.placeFormDom(XFAFlattener.java:1158)
    at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.xtra.xfa.XFAFlattener.flatten(XFAFlattener.java:897)
    at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.xtra.xfa.XFAFlattener.flatten(XFAFlattener.java:444)
    at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.xtra.xfa.XFAFlattener.flatten(XFAFlattener.java:312)
    at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.xtra.xfa.XFAFlattener.flatten(XFAFlattener.java:282)
```

Comment: XFA Worker is a closed source add on for iText. It is not available in an open source version. If you are using XFA Worker, you are a customer of iText Software. Please create a ticket on the issue tracker at iText Software.

Comment: I am using trial version of xfa worker to see whether it's suitable for my application or not. Also can you share some idea why it's coming for each and every document  .Although I am getting my result but for this error my log file's are flooded with data. Please help

Comment: Please share a sample document and code to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I debug further and found flatten method from XFAFlattener class is getting this message. Sorry my application is too big to paste here . I am using public void flatten(PdfReader reader) method in my class

Comment: Without the sample document, we can't help you. You will have to share the form and a data set so that we can examine the problem.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/0BwvDBuyk4wwqWURlNUh6RWJqeW8

Comment: @spondonmajumdar your google share cannot be accessed.

Comment: again I am encounter with a different problem We are using itext xfa worker, and recently we noticed that the form values are changing in destination flat pdf. Can you please try to help us on that. I am also attaching source pdf and flatten pdf

source https://www.dropbox.com/s/9za2ewl3a845bjc/Attachment%201.pdf?dl=0

flatten https://www.dropbox.com/s/i9qc0aiob2vp6rc/Attachment%201_flatten.pdf?dl=0

Comment: There indeed are differences in the original and the flattened representation of the field contents, some of them merely changed line break positions but some of them actually different field contents. @BrunoLowagie you might be interested...

Comment: @BrunoLowagie  let me give you more deeper umderstanding from my side. 1: xfa worker is not able to flatten value which has more than 10 numeric digit (like 10000000000, this is coming some junk value in my pdf , i believe its integer overflow and small bug. 2: you are internally extracting xml from the pdf and then flattening it, some of the information is getting lost while extracting xml information, look the address field in my source document). I hope I am able to help you a little

Comment: @spondonmajumdar I didn't write XFA Worker. I am not on that project. You need the support team. The support team is not on StackOverflow. The support team is paid to provide support. They don't spend paid time on SO. They only work for paying customers.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie I understand your issue , fair enough. Can you give me an assurance if we take the paid access of itext, they are able to solve the issue asap and in future bugs will be resolved if we open issue in tracker.

Comment: @spondonmajumdar That's a question for sales. Please contact them and ask them that question. In general, I hear from customers that there issues get fixed. XFA is a huge spec. There are many different ways to do things and even Acrobat doesn't follow everything that is written in the XFA spec.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie We have asked the sales team of itext about the issue ,also ready to take paid version of xfa worker. Can you please speed up the process as we are running out of time (this weekend our products will go live ).

Comment: @spondonmajumdar As far as I can see the issue has been fixed. Can you confirm?

Comment: @mkl the above problem has been solved but the same problem is coming from other document.I have updated a request to them and I think their Belgium team is looking into it.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie can you please tell me how to change the page size (I want to increase the top portion of the page) using itext.

Comment: @spondonmajumdar as mkl has told you, you need to get in touch with the team in Belgium.